# Restart game XNA

Tags: c#, xna, 2d-games

How can I make a game to restart when I lose? My game is structured in 3 parts: mainMenu,Game and the end (when you lose). So I divided the Update and draw method in 3 parts. Now I need the option to restart the game if I lose.

```
bool lost=false; //when it is "true" I lost
if(lost==true)
{
    if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
    {
    // Restart game
    }
}
```

Comment: When `the end` is at display and user presses enter display the main menu screen.

Comment: yes but It doesn't function anyway, because if i make "new  game" in main menu it sends me directly to the "End" screen

Comment: you also have to set lost = false before displaying the main menu screen

Comment: ...so you have to reset your game state in that event.

Comment: XNA is no gamemaker, you have to code all. if you are using game states, then change state to mainscreen (to update and draw ONLY mainscreen), and before that dispose all elements.

Comment: What @Davor said. That's the beauty of XNA, really. You get to do everything yourself, and therefor you can make everything exactly as you want it.

Comment: the problem is that , when I lose and make "new game" the monsters that I killed before are still dead :|

Comment: If the monsters have states, you need to reset them too. Create a method that resets all states and your "lost"-boolean to its default states. Call it when you restart the game

Comment: Thank you very much! now I am going to try it

Comment: The monsters are made all by same method: 1) create a class of the monster ,2) in Game1 create a List 3)in Initialize i initialise it 4)I load them in LoadContent and put the positions 5)I update it in Update method and I REMOVE the monsters if they for rxample have visible=false(it means that i shooted them) 6) in Draw method I draw them. Now , if I removed them, can i get them back?

Comment: beauty of XNA is that you have control over every single pixel in screen, but that require coding. no drag and drop items. it's good to practice in XNA and then switch to some other game engine. actually what you asked is more related to programm language, not XNA iself. how to add items into array or list how to remove them and other.

Comment: so is there a way to reset a list? (sorry for  multiple questions but I am new in XNA and I have never worked with these kind of things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make sure you set `lost = false` when you restart

Comment: It is.. now I can "restart" again but the enemies and the others objects aren't in their initial position because i killed/destroyed them  before. Now I just need to know how to reinitialize the Lists of the objects/enemies.

Comment: you can create a method that initializes your game world. 
Call it in load_content() or initialize() and also call it where you set lost = false

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to show more for anyone to be able to give more specific help, so all I can say is that you need to somehow reset your game state in that event right there -- and this depends heavily on how you yourself built it. For example, a common scheme is to have an IScreen interface that all screens implement, and the Game class simply holds one of these. To switch from one to another (e.g. from a, say, "WorldScreen" to a "MainScreen"), you'd simply initialize the MainScreen and throw away the WorldScreen object.

Comment: For example i made  a "pause" system. if i press "P" key  there come out 3 things: Resume , Main menu, Exit.  If I go back to Main Menu and then I try to choose again "Play" it is not a new game it is just a "resume"

Comment: Look my other Question: How to reset a list  XNA and C#. I put there more details.

Comment: @FkinP3rfect if you switch to a main menu object, don't keep the world screen object. Just throw it away and re-initialize it the same way you did the first time.

Comment: Done!! it functions but it has lagg for 5 seconds (more or less) becauze it has to update and initialize all. I think I have to draw an image "loading" when it loads all just to not show the laggy screen